# env: node\r: No such file or directory with browserify-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, npm, browserify

All was well. Wanted to use the ios simulator but xcode wanted to update. Why not? Did that. All was well. Done a git add, commit and merge. Once I've merged:

> Error while running `/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/demo/node_modules/.bin/browserifyinc --transform reactify --extension=".jsx" --list --cachefile=/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/demo/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/browserifyinc-cache.json -o "/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/demo/tmp/cache/browserify-rails/output20160319-1425-142q6j7" -`:
>
> env: node\r: No such file or directory

I'm on Mac 10.11.13

Ran these commands but nothing changed: `rake tmp:cache:clear` and `rm -rf ./tmp`

Heard the issue was caused by a git commit but not sure how when it was working. All I did was updated xcode and then a git merge. Checked out on the last working branch but same issue.

Comment: What's the output of `which node` ?

Comment: @gnerkus `/usr/local/bin/node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dos line ending on the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line of your script (`\r\n` instead of `\n`, and that may have been replicated on other lines as well); execute [`fromdos`](http://macappstore.org/tofrodos/) on the script file *or* you could use `tr` like

```
tr -d '\015' < scriptfile > scriptfile.new
```

then

```
mv scriptfile.new scriptfile
```

Comment: I dont understand this answer, sorry.

Comment: The file `/Users/sylar/Sites/rails/demo/node_modules/.bin/browserifyinc` (or a script it invokes) has a dos new-line on the **first** line.